# How to fix: ImportError: cannot import name TwitterRestPager

Tags: python, twitter, importerror, tweepy

I am using some GitHub code to test TwitterAPI

```
import re, textwrap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse
```

**NOTE**: Must have TwitterAPI Installed

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
from TwitterAPI import TwitterRestPager
```

I installed TwitterAPI, but once getting an error while running .py

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Twitter_Counter.py", line
>   17, in    from TwitterAPI import TwitterRestPager 
>   ImportError: cannot import name TwitterRestPager

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [virtualenv utility](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), because the issue here might be that you are installing TwitterAPI (I assume using PIP) for a different python version than what you are running your script with. Virtualenv will make it so that your python-related binaries are "linked together" and isolated from the rest of the system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that´s not solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

I Think that the `TwitterAPI` package version that you use has this error.

You can try:

```
pip install TwitterAPI --upgrade
```

to upgrade your package and check if it will be imported correctly.

Or instead, manually specify older version of the package.

Comment: Hi, upgraded as above -- TwitterAPI (2.5.9) -- but still having the same issue.
Successfully installed TwitterAPI-2.5.9 certifi-2018.11.29 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 oauthlib-3.0.1 requests-2.21.0 requests-oauthlib-1.2.0 urllib3-1.24.1